# My Calathea zebrina is having burnt edges in almost all leaves and even the new baby leaves are burnt

Tags: plant-care, leaves, indoors

I have attached the pictures of the plant here. I water sufficiently and I place the plant in moderate humidity and light.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would repot them, using new, healthy soil. Don't go for the cheap stuff, the whole point is for the plant to have nutritious, well-drained soil. I like to add organic compost from my compost pile to the mix, it works really well.

Also, be conservative on the watering, less is more.